# Как правильно позиционировать элементы в css?

Tags: css

Как правильно позиционировать элементы в css? С помощью translate или position? Например мне нужно расположить картинку в определенном месте, с помощью какого свойства это можно сделать правильно?

Comment: всё очень зависит от конкретной задачи и конкретных условий

Comment: По ситуации. . .

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от ситуации, но думаю, position - для этого и создан. left, right, top, bottom, z-index в помощь.

```
https://idg.net.ua/blog/uchebnik-css/razmetka-css/position
```